# Applescript: expected end of line but found number

Tags: scripting, syntax, numbers, applescript, itunes

I'm  trying to automatically select a menu item in iTunes using applescript. However, every time that I run this script I get an error message that says "expected end of line but found number, and points me to "scrollarea 1". I'm using Apple's UIElement inspector to get the names of the GUI elements in iTunes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's what I have so far:

```
tell application "iTunes"
      activate
      delay 10
      tell application "System Events"
            key code 53
            tell outline 1 of scrollarea 1 of window 1
                 click menu 1
            end tell
      end tell
end tell
```

Well, I have it clicking what I need it to be clicking. The only problem now is that it's not actually clicking it, it's just returning the AXValue. I need it to actually click the item in iTunes itself.

Comment: what are you trying to click?

Comment: I'm attempting to click the first device in the iTunes devices list. I just found it in the UI (thanks, btw) but for some reason it isn't clicking it. Instead, it's returning the text. I've got

tell row 11 of outline 1 of scroll area 2 of window "iTunes" of application "iTunes"
click static text 1
end tell

Comment: I tried select as well, but it did the same thing. I'm now wondering if there is any way at all for applescript to send a real mouse click. If not, would coco, bash, or python be able to send a real click?

Comment: rather than clicking/selecting the static text, try the row as I have in my answer. On Snow Leopard my script selects my iPod from the list.

Comment: I go back on that. Thank you sir/madam. I would give you a point if I could!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
activate application "iTunes"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "iTunes"
        select row 15 of outline 1 of scroll area 2 of window "iTunes"
    end tell
end tell
```